# How do I use the command: HttpEntity?

Tags: android, https, android-2.3-gingerbread

I wish to settle my long term problem by this question and hope you guys would help, but firstly; I have been having issues to connect to a HTTPS self-signed certificate server for almost 3 weeks. Despite the multiple solutions here, I cannot seem to resolve my problem. Probably I did not know how to use it properly or did not have some files or imported the correct libraries.

I came across some websites that requires me to download a certificate from the https site that I am trying to connect into, and when I did that. I have to do the some steps before I can use the certificate or keystore that I created. I got this solution from this website:

[Android: Trusting SSL certificates](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/)

```
// Instantiate the custom HttpClient
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.mydomain.ch/rest/contacts/23");
// Execute the GET call and obtain the response
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
```

I have a problem, after the last line, as stated above. What do I do with the responseEntity? How do I use it if I wish to display the https website on a WebView? Some help and explanation would be nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the content from the `HttpEntity` the **correct** way does **not** include calling `HttpEntity#getContent()` to retrieve a stream and doing tons of pointless stuff already available in the Android SDK.

Try this instead.

```
// Execute the GET call and obtain the response
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

// Retrieve a String from the response entity
String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

// Now content will contain whatever the server responded with and you
// can pass it to your WebView using #loadDataWithBaseURL
```

Consider using [WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) when displaying `content` - it behaves a lot nicer.

Comment: ooo, I am blind. I didn't see this answer. Anyway, I am ending my work and will try this when I get home. Do check this site as I would definitely reply if it works or not!!

Comment: I managed to run the app without having any runtime errors, but I do not get any output. After some tedious bebugging. The getResponse = client.execute(get) returns a null value. I understood why I may get a null return. Your codes you provided requires me to use try-catch method. The outcome would look something like this: `try {
   getResponse = client.execute(get);
   HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
    content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: Hi, it has been awhile since I was doing this app. I tried your `String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);` works pretty nicely, but it kinda returns a HTML codes rather than a URL link. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. Is there an URL link in the HTML response from the server that you need to fetch and use later on - or is this for processing a redirect?

Comment: Ah sorry! got that fixed now, you are right about the loadDataWithBaseURL. I just didnt know how to use it properly!! Managed to solve it with the help of others in this site! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `responseEntity.getContent()` to get response in **InputStream** against your requested URL. Use that stream in your way to present data as you want. For example, if the expected data is String, so you may simply convert this stream into string with the following method:

```
/**
 * Converts InputStream to String and closes the stream afterwards
 * @param is Stream which needs to be converted to string
 * @return String value out form stream or NULL if stream is null or invalid.
 * Finally the stream is closed too. 
 */
public static String streamToString(InputStream is) {
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader tmp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),65728);
        String line = null;

        while ((line = tmp.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        //close stream
        is.close();

        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and raju's answer? For this line: `(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8)` and `(new InputStreamReader(is),65728)`

Comment: He is just setting the character encoding to **ASCII**. However, in my answer I'm relying on string's default encoding which is **UTF-8**. By default, all Json and XML streams are encoded in UTF-8. So i guess its reasonable to give a try to the default one first, and if it doesn't work as expected then move to any other encoding. Or check with your server to confirm which scheme it uses. Besieds, about buffer reading length either 8 or 65728, well i'm simply setting it to a higher value so that the data is read in bigger chunks rather than small. So its up to you.

Comment: I see, I am having problem with Raju's answer. How do I implement your code? After I type this down, how do I use it?

Comment: Add the method *streamToString* in a new class for example **Helper** and then call it as: `String result = Helper.streamToString(responseEntity.getContent());`. Afterwards, assign **result** string to your TextView.setText() or log it

Comment: Ok, I am DEFINITELY doing something wrong here. I get the same errors for both you and raju. I used the `String result` on a WebView, is that allowed? To me since its a string value, why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();
 try{
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
         String line="0";
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
          }

     String   result=sb.toString();
          is.close();
 }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
          }
```

you will have all the content in the String "result"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you mind explaining what is "iso-8859-1" and "8" means? Or what happens if I do not put it down?

Comment: I get an error saying, I need to use a try-catch exception. What should I do? I did kinda use your method in my main activity, is that the wrong place to put this code?

Comment: I may have done something wrong in my methods. I am getting a lot of errors after I compile and build the project. Do you want me to update my question and post all the error message? Or can I zip the file and send to you to check for me? No worries, I am using a test https site which I am comfortable to disclose.