# Fetch json from url giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, http

I am fetching URL from below URL but i got following error

```
 url = "http://qrpromenad.azurewebsites.net/api/question?id=1&imei=35404304";


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();  // here i got null value

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The following is logcat error

```
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579): java.lang.NullPointerException
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at         com.qrcodetest.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:40)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at com.qrcodetest.Result$FetchURL.doInBackground(Result.java:50)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at com.qrcodetest.Result$FetchURL.doInBackground(Result.java:1)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
       04-17 16:00:12.739: W/System.err(4579):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

but if i use another url like http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ it is working fine

i have used POST method but still NULL is returning

```
     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Const.POST_URL);
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", "123456"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        System.out.println("httpEntity "+httpEntity); // here is null
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {// false
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
```

Comment: Which line is line 40 in your snippet?

Comment: What's the line giving the NPE? (i.e. line 40 of your JSONParser class)

Comment: Have you modified anything in the PHP script. check whether it is properly returning the json response you need.

Comment: Why do you use `getJSONFromURL()` when the next moment you contact the server yourself? If you really need to `POST`, the `getJSONFromUrl()` may not get a reasonable answer.

Comment: *Always* check the HTTP response status (with `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`) before trying to read it's data. You may very well be bombing on `is = httpEntity.getContent()`, assuming you've shown all your code.

Comment: Funny, you were editing your code as I was making my comment! Ok, you need to check your response status, looks like your server is returning you an error, and there is no entity to read data from, hence the NPE.

Comment: Hello Perception just check that link on your browser it is returning value

Comment: Do not know but if i use last url it is working fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679673/how-do-i-use-the-command-httpentity  ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684086/getting-the-response-body-of-httpresponse

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit: can you Saw us your full java file Source code here?

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit - you should be using a GET for the request, not a POST (POST's to it don't return any data, hence the NPE). Also, move the status line check to ***before*** you read the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in question does not support posts (you can test that yourself with any kind of REST client). But, as you yourself have indicated, it does work with GET's. So switch up your code to something like as shown below and problem solved:

```
final String url = "http://qrpromenad.azurewebsites.net/api/question?id=1&imei=35404304";

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);

String responseData = null;
final int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    responseData = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
} else {
    System.err.println("HTTP request failed with status " + status);
}

System.out.println(responseData);
```

*You need to add back in (of course) some more advanced error handling*

Comment: Thank you soooo much Perception  :)